# An encryption algorithm that works out of the box with php and iOS

Tags: php, objective-c, api, cryptography, mcrypt

I am developing an API in which I will be talking to from an iOS Application. In my authentication scheme, both the server and the client has the **`APP_SECRET`**, What happens during login:

1. The iOS app sends the **`APP_ID`** along with an encrypted **payload**. 
   The payload is just a JSON object with the user's username,password.
   **The payload is encoded using the `APP_SECRET`** and is sent to the server.
2. The server receives **`APP_ID`** and the payload from the iOS app, it
   will search for the APP_SECRET associated with the given APP_ID in
   the database and **it will try to decrypt the payload using the
   found `APP_SECRET`**, once it's decrypted, it checks the username,pass
   combination against the database and typically logs the user in.

Apparently, I would need to use the same encryption/decryption algorithm in both the backend and the frontend(iOS).

I tried using the default **mcrypt** *AES256* aka *RIJNDAEL* algorithm to decrypt the payload which looks like that in php codeigniter:

```
$decoded_payload = $this->encrypt->decode(urldecode($login_payload),$secret_key);
```

And on the iOS app, I encrypt the login string in the same order:

```
//Login String    
NSString * jsonPayload = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"email":userName,@"password":password} options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//AES256 Encrypt with APP_SECRET   
NSString * payload = [jsonPayload AES256EncryptWithKey:secret];

//URL Encode
payload = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) payload,
                                                                        NULL,
                                                                        CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
                                                                        kCFStringEncodingASCII));
```

What really happens is that the encrypted payload is completely different from that expected on the backend and decrypting it using php always returns wrong answers. I am looking for a concrete solution for this problem, even if the solution will require me to change the algorithm. My questions are straight forward.

- **How to exactly mimic the default AES256 mcrypt encryption on iOS side using
  Objective-C?**
- **If you think the answer for the above question is tedious, do you
  know any other alternatives that will work out of the box without
  much dirty work to ensure that the encryption/decryption result will be the same in the front(ObjC) and the backend(PHP)?**

Comment: Seems like you are trying to reinvent [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). Is there a reason you can't use an established standard?

Comment: Could you please show more of the code that you use in PHP? I've got a sneaking suspicion that you are not using `mcrypt` as you should. If transport layer security would suffice, then please keep to TLS. Your scheme for instance may be vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

Comment: APP_SECRET is an oxymoron. You can't keep any values embedded in an application running on an untrusted iOS device secret from the user. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @CodesInChaos the APP_SECRET is just used to encrypt the login payload. Some sort of obfuscation for data sent on the wire. Nothing more, nothing less. My actual goal is to unify the encryption/decryption functionality across the iOS device and the PHP Backend. Using the same algorithm yields different results. I have came to a work-around and will share it later with the community!